# How do I group documents into separate groups and then find average of the different groups in mongodb (nosql)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents and I need to group the documents based on its month and display it as quarter 1,2,3 or 4 in the output. I also need to find the average value of the total "avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh" for each quarter. I am not sure how to do this.
This is an example of a document in the collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63074885ff3acbe0d63d6c68"),
    "year" : "2005",
    "month" : "1",
    "housing_type" : "Public Housing",
    "sub_housing_type" : "Public Housing",
    "avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh" : "89.4\r"
},
```

Two more things to take note of;

1. All the numbers are in string format and not integer
2. I need to exclude a "sub_housing_type" called "overall" as it should not be part of the calculations

Here is an example of the average calculation
This is the document for sub_housing_type : 3 room
Month 1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63074885ff3acbe0d63d6c6a"),
    "year" : "2005",
    "month" : "1",
    "housing_type" : "Public Housing",
    "sub_housing_type" : "3 Room ",
    "avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh" : "82.2\r"
},
```

Taking documents for the 3 months for the sub_housing_type I need to sum up the "avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh" for each of the month and divide it by 3 to find the average. That value now has to be in the output in the "quarterly_avg"
So in this case it will be 81.4 as (82.2+81.0+81.1)/3 gives us 81.43

I am not sure how to approach this. Someone please help!

I need to get an output which has the year, quarter, sub_housing_type, and the quarterly average for each quarter. An example of the output is as follows

```
{
    "year" : "2005",
    "quarter" : "1",
    "sub_housing_type" : "Public Housing",
    "quarterly_avg" : "89.4\r"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 "$addFields": {
  "Q4": {
    "$toString": {
      $toInt: {
        $divide: [
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $toInt: "$month"
              },
              2
            ]
          },
          3
        ]
      }
    }
   },
   av: {
    $toDouble: {
      $substr: [
        "$avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh",
        0,
        {
          $add: [
            {
              $strLenCP: "$avg_mthly_hh_tg_consp_kwh"
            },
            -1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
   }
   }
  },
  {
   $group: {
  _id: "$Q4",
  avgq: {
    "$avg": "$av"
  },
  sub_housing_type: {
    "$last": "$sub_housing_type"
  },
  year: {
    "$last": "$year"
  },
  
  }
 },
 {
   $project: {
  _id: 0,
  quarter: "$_id",
  year: 1,
  sub_housing_type: 1,
  "quarterly_avg": {
    "$concat": [
      {
        "$toString": {
          "$round": [
            "$avgq",
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      "\r"
    ]
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Add two new fields Q4 that contain the quarter number (1-4) and av that contain the decimal value of monthly consumption.
2. Group by those fileds and find the average per quarter
3. Project the necessary values in the needed format

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X3-wDR6kVXf)

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply
In the collection, some of the values are listed as "na" and this is making the $convert not work. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You can add condition to switch for na values set 0

Comment: maybe good to add example for such values , are they equal to "N/A" , "" , "na" or different?